# Shower door alignment with small and large allen key bolts

Tags: doors, shower, glass

My showerdoor sticks, and needs to go less far out.

There are small and large allen key bolts at both top and bottom hinges.

How do these work? Which ones do I need to loosen or tighten?

[image: hinge]

Comment: Seems to me like the Allen screws clamp the hinge to the two pieces of glass.  You'll just have to experiment with the positioning, since we have no clue what "sticks, and needs to go less far out" means to you.  The small set screws may adjust the hinge position, or simply the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two smaller ones are the adjusters.
Clockwise should move the door outwards, away from that hinge; anti-clockwise inwards, towards it.

Move them as a pair, half a turn on each until you're happy. Your first half turn will likely confirm you're going in the right direction - check it by closing the door each time.

Watch out you don't go too far inwards so that it catches on the fixed pane. That could easily break it.

If you run out of adjustment & it's still not right, then you may get a bit more out of the large screws. The holes those fit through are going to be larger than the screw, possibly allowing you a bit of wiggle-room if you loosen them all.
Get someone to hold the door for you as you loosen it, don't take them right out, just loose enough for it to move - and again watch out you don't hit the fixed pane.

Be really careful tightening back up again. Count how many flats you back it off to move, and tighten back up the same number, unless it's obviously slack.